# Searching multiple columns in DB

Tags: php, search

I have a searching script, now I want to let it search multiple columns. 
Like now I have "plaats" as a database column. But I also want track, straat, postcode, plaats to be found in the search option.

I have added the AND / OR rule but then it shows ALL rows in the database.

Can someone help me out with this one :)

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE plaats LIKE '%".$term."%'";
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){
        echo "<tr class=\"border_bottom\">";
        echo "<td><a href=\"https://jouw.postnl.nl/#!/track-en-trace/".$row['track']."/".$row['land']."/".$row['postcode']."\">Bekijk Status</a>";
        echo "<td>".$row['track']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['straat']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['postcode']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['plaats']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['land']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['klantnummer']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$$row[id]\">Wijzigen</a></td>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please be a bit more specific what you are trying to achieve, and where / how it fails.  
Also, the mysql_* functions in PHP are deprecated. That means: Don't use them any more! They will be removed in the future. Use PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: Now its : 

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE plaats LIKE '%".$term."%'";`

Its needs to be something like : 

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE plaats OR straat OR track OR land OR datum LIKE '%".$term."%'";`

Comment: @DavePiersma you can see my answer.

Comment: So, you are trying to find records, where the search term is either in "plaats" or in "straat" or in ... ? Is that correct?

Comment: @Burki thats correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE 
    plaats LIKE '%".$term."%' 
    OR straat LIKE '%".$term."%' 
    OR track LIKE '%".$term."%' 
    OR land LIKE '%".$term."%' 
    OR datum LIKE '%".$term."%'";
```

That means: you need to compare every column with the term you are looking for.

Please keep in mind that you should not use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Also, you amy want to consider a somewhat more complex stragety: i strongly doubt that there really is a scenario where the same term might be found either in "street" or in "datum". But that is just a side note.

Comment: Could you help me out with 1 other problem ? @burki

Comment: I will try :-) Would you like to ask a new question, or shall we talk in the chat?

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE plaats LIKE '%".$term."%'";
```

To

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);

$searchTerms = "plaats LIKE '%".$term."%'
        OR track LIKE '%".$term."%'
        OR straat LIKE '%".$term."%'
        OR postcode LIKE '%".$term."%'
    ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tt WHERE $searchTerms";
```

**Warning**: MYSQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: it only finds "plaats"

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding this code.

```
  $qry = "select * from  tt where 
  plaats LIKE '%".$term."%' or  track, LIKE '%".$term."%' or straat LIKE   '%".$term."%' or postcode LIKE '%".$term."%' or plaats  LIKE '%".$term."%'";
echo $qry;
```